# ld: framework not found Pods_MyProject_MyProjectTests

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

Trying to do some unit testing with Firebase, but I'm having compiler problems. When I try to run a test, I get the following error:

```
ld: framework not found Pods_MyProject_MyProjectTests
```

Pod:

```
platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'MyProject' do
  use_frameworks!

# ignore all warnings from all pods
inhibit_all_warnings!

# Pods for MyProject
pod 'CoreXLSX'
pod 'Eureka'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'ProgressHUD'
pod 'GoogleSignIn'
pod 'SteviaLayout'

target 'MyProjectTests' do
  inherit! :search_paths
  # Pods for testing
  end

target 'MyProjectUITests' do
  inherit! :search_paths
  # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

You need core. I'd provide more information, but it's a "duplicate answer", so thank mod Yvette Colomb for this vague and useless answer.